# Jquery: finding element with classname stored in variable

Tags: jquery

(Edited with more detail just in case someone else has a similar question)

I've got an image map which needs to reveal a div on rollover of a hotspot. I've given my areas on the image map classes, and using jQuery want to reveal it's corresponding div, e.g.,

`area shape="rect" coords="601,31,723,107" href="#" alt="Some Location" class="some-location"`

Each area has a different location and therefore different classname.

I'm not sure how to reference an element with its classname stored in a variable?
For example, the code I currently have to get the class name on hovering over an area on the image map is:

`var hotspot = $(this).attr("class");`

Now I want to do something like:

`$(div.hotspot).show();`

The above is not working - could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string concatenation:

```
$("div." + hotspot)
```

Obviously this only works if `hotspot` only contains **one** class (see Reigel's comment). If it contains more classes, you have to replace the white spaces by a dot:

```
$("div." + hotspot.replace(' ', '.'))
```

*(assuming that multiple white spaces between class names get trimmed automatically but I am not sure about that, otherwise you have to use the regular expression `/\s+/`*)

Comment: what if that would result to `$('div.class1 class2 class3 class4').show();` ? as `hotspot="class1 class2 class3 class4"`

Comment: @Reigel: Oh I have not thought about that, as the OP wrote *have to get the class **name** .*. But you are right....

Answer (score 3):

```
$('.' + hotspot).show();
```

since your variable `hotspot` contains a **class string**, you need to pass it as a `string selector`.

It does not make much **sense** anyway, since you would access the same element from which you received that class name.
If you already `queried` that element once, you can (and should!) **store / cache** the `jQuery object` into a variable and access it from there again.

Comment: what if `hotspot` is now holding multiple class names?

Comment: @Reigel: as I stated, it does not make sense at all.

Comment: no, I was pointing to this, `$('.' + hotspot).show();` what if that would result to `$('.class1 class2 class3 class4').show();` ?

Comment: Hi jAndy - I'm receiving the classname from the area element in the imagemap but showing a div with the same class, so they are 2 different elements with the same classname.

Comment: @pingu: I see, in that case `Felix Kling` answer is the one.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#divid").find(hotspot);
```

You can use this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a string argument to `$()`
you missed the quotes in your example.
you need to do `$('.hotspot').show()`
You might also have `var c = '.hotspot';$(c).show()`